# Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with SmallIntTable SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to execute a simple stored procedure in SQL Server.

```
USE [dbname]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_storprocname]
        @ID = NULL,
        @SomeID = 123456,
        @AddressTypeIDs = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

What I'm getting is an error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_storprocname, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with SmallIntTable

From what I understand, it expects to get some kind of an array with numbers in  `@AddressTypeIDs` parameter. I don't need to filter results by that field. How can I pass a correct value there?

Comment: we need the code of your sp to help you with this one

Comment: @Lamak Can you tell me how to get it? Modify button on right-click on SP is greyed out and I don't see any other option to see its code.

Comment: Then I would say that you don't have the permissions to see it. You could try `sp_helptext 'usp_storprocname'`, but I would bet it won't work either

Comment: @Lamak Tells me `There is no text for object 'usp_storprocname'.` Is there any way to pass a `SmallIntTable` to this stored proc without knowing its code?

Comment: `@ID` or `@AddressTypeIDs` isn't nullable in that proc. Thus, you must pass in a value.

Comment: Open the Programmability tree under your database and look under Types>User-Defined Table Types, and find out what a `SmallIntTable` looks like.

Comment: @TabAlleman It has one column: `SmallIntCol(smallint, not null)`. I'm not sure how to create an item of this type to pass it as a parameter to my stored proc though.

Comment: @MartinSmith It looks like this stored proc requires it: `Error occured in usp_mystoredproc :: Atleast 1 contact type must be specified`. I just want to pass an empty array or some values there.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, that's what I want. I'm not sure how to pass some value there. We've already found that it's a custom type `SmallIntTable` though I don't know how to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you execute the stored proc, Declare a variable of type `SmallIntTable`.

This will be a table with a single column, as you have learned.

Insert whatever values you wish into that table, and then when you Execute the stored procedure, pass that variable as the value for the `@AddressTypeIDs` parameter.

e.g. as below

```
USE [dbname]

GO

DECLARE @return_value INT
DECLARE @AddressTypeIDs dbo.SMALLINTCOL;

INSERT INTO @AddressTypeIDs
VALUES     (1);

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[usp_storprocname]
  @ID = NULL,
  @SomeID = 123456,
  @AddressTypeIDs = @AddressTypeIDs

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```